# Matriz de 1's y 0's (como un tablero de ajedrez)

Tags: python

Quiero que el user ingrese la cantidad de filas y columnas y que mi programa muestre una matriz de 1's y 0's. Esta propuesta la vi por ahi en Internet pensé que me sería fácil pero no xD. ¿alguna pista? Solo pido eso, un tip :)

```
"""
ej de salida:
ing filas: 5
ing columnas: 6
1 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0
"""
```

```
m=[]
x=int(input("cuantas filas queris: "))
y=int(input("ctas columnas: "))
for f in range(x):
    m.append([]) #le agrego una fila
    for c in range(y):
        #llenado de la primera columna de la fila
        if c==0 and f % 2 == 0:
            m[f].append(1)
        elif c==0 and f % 2 != 0:
            m[f].append(0)
        #llenado de las filas considerando el valor del primer elemento 
        elif m[f][c]==1:
            m[f].append(0)
        elif m[f][c]==0:
            m[f].append(1)

for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        print(m[i][j])
    print()

#output:
#elif m[f][c]==1:
#IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Cuál es el problema que tienes con el código que muestras?

Comment: Me dice que el index está fuera de rango en `elif m[f][c]==1:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo único que necesitas es imprimir la matriz, podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
x=int(input("¿cuántas filas quieres?: "))
y=int(input("¿cuántas columnas quieres?: "))

for n in range(x):
    for m in range(y):
        print((m + n) % 2, end=' ')
    print('\n', end='')
```

Con esto  para una entrada `x=5` `y=6` la salida que obtendrías en sería:

```
0 1 0 1 0 1 
1 0 1 0 1 0 
0 1 0 1 0 1 
1 0 1 0 1 0 
0 1 0 1 0 1
```

Con `(n + m) % 2` lo que consigues es devolver el modulo de la suma de `n` y `m`, por lo que si el nº es impar saldrá 1 y si es par, saldrá 0.

Si lo quieres al revés, es decir, que empiece por 1, con cambiarlo por `(n + m + 1) % 2` te saldría:

```
1 0 1 0 1 0 
0 1 0 1 0 1 
1 0 1 0 1 0 
0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0
```

Ahora bien, si lo que quieres es guardar esta matriz en una variable para utilizarla más adelante, necesitarás entonces guardarla por ejemplo en listas anidadas, en un array de `numpy`, o en un `DataFrame`.

**Listas anidadas (por comprensión de listas):**

```
print([[((m + n) % 2) for m in range(y)] for n in range(x)])
```

Salida:

```
[[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]]
```

**Array de numpy:**

```
import numpy as np

x=int(input("¿cuántas filas quieres?: "))
y=int(input("¿cuántas columnas quieres?: "))

# En este caso x e y toman los valores de los índices de la matriz
def fn(x, y):
    return((x + y) % 2)

a = np.fromfunction(fn, (x, y), dtype='int')

print(a)
```

Una entrada de `x=5` `y=6` daría el siguiente resultado almacenado en `a`:

```
[[0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 1]]
```

Aquí también puedes hacer que el primer elemento sea 1 cambiando:

```
return((x + y + 1) % 2)
```

**Dataframe de pandas:**

Y por último, también podrías transformarlo a un `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.DataFrame(a))
```

Salida:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  1  0  1  0  1  0
1  0  1  0  1  0  1
2  1  0  1  0  1  0
3  0  1  0  1  0  1
4  1  0  1  0  1  0
```

Comment: El OP no indica nada de `numpy` ni tiene dicha etiqueta. ¿ Podrías adaptar tu respuesta a `python` *puro* y *duro* ?

Comment: Hola @Trauma, Estaba ya editándolo para incluirlo. Como el OP ha hablado de matrices, me parecía oportuno incluir esas posibilidades para que la respuesta fuese más completa. Crees oportuno eliminarlas y dejar solo la parte de python puro y duro?

Comment: Al final lo que he creído más conveniente ha sido, poner primero la respuesta con python puro y posteriormente explicar las otras posibilidades después.

Comment: Más claro no pudo quedar! Gracias!